# How to disable "Component Browser" in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Following: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/WSf01dbd23413dda0e-3f89e8d411fae637e44-8000.html

I already commented out the RDS in `\JRun4\servers\[name]\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\WEB-INF\web.xml`

However, the RDS tab is still there in the CF Administrator, and browsing to a CFC still redirect me to `/CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc`

How to disable "Component Browser" in ColdFusion?

Thanks

Comment: found this: but seems like a hack? http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/7/19/Ask-a-Jedi-Preventing-direct-access-to-a-CFC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Component Browser" cannot be disabled--it is a hard-wired function of ColdFusion, which automatically fires when you make a web request to the full location where a .CFC resides--and is unrelated to RDS, whether it is enabled or not.

You will have to decide upon a methodology that you want to approach to prevent direct access to your CFCs, and implement it that way, instead. Such options are:

1. Disabling the "auto-documentation" of a CFC, as described in the post provided by [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35634/henry) above (Source: [Ray Camden](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com)).
2. Remove the /CFIDE virtual mapping from any of your public facing websites, so that a direct .CFC web request results in a HTTP 500 (as cfcexplorer will no longer be accessible).

A slicker option altogether is to make your **public-facing websites use a different virtual /CFIDE directory**:

1. Remove the existing /CFIDE mapping for your public-facing site (#2 above)
2. Create a new folder in your public facing site called "CFIDE".
3. Within that directory, create a folder called "componentutils".
   , 4. Within "componentutils", create a single file, "cfcexplorer.cfc", which you will then use to make a single  call, and return a 403 (Forbidden) code to the browser:

   <cfheader statuscode="403" statustext="Forbidden" />

This option is good, because you not only hide your CFCs from direct access via the implicit functionality of the Component Browser, you also **hide your CF Administrator from the public** (which many CF sites often forget about).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want your CFCs to be browseable, don't put them in a directory that's browseable!  Only files you intend to be browseable ought to be exposed by the web server.

I think the problem here is not the CFC explorer's functionality, it's that you've got stuff you don't want to be browsed to in a browseable location.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete/rename the cfcexplorer.cfc?